# Issue while printing an image using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I have written a code to print an image using javascript as follows

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function printIt() {
        var win = window.open('', 'popup', 'location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=800,height=600');
        if (win) {
            var imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=chkImage.ClientID%>').src;
            win.document.write('<img src="' + imageControl + '">');
            win.document.close();
            win.focus();
            win.print();
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and my image control is defined as follows

`<asp:Image ID="chkImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CheckPreview.aspx" />`

but when printing I an getting some extra fields on the paper as per attached in the image can some one tell how can I avoid those while printing[image]

My extra field are which I marked in red I don't want to print those

Comment: You can not remove that with javascript, this are come from the browser, and you can remove it from the print dialog of the browser.

Comment: from file->page setup dialog under firefox, @User

Comment: `ArsenMkrt` can you post it as answer i will mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean print the special section of the page? if that is right. you can use the print css for that, you use some print javascript plugin, like the JQuery print plugin.

Try [This](http://forums.asp.net/p/1545456/3781791.aspx#3781791) or [This](http://forums.asp.net/p/1535183/3733113.aspx#3733113)

Or you can read the print content to new page via the javascript method.

```
<script language="javascript">
function CallPrint(strid)
{
var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
//var WinPrint = window.open('');
var WinPrint = window.open('','','letf=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
// prtContent.innerHTML = strOldOne;
}



<a href="javascript:CallPrint('DivContent')"><img src="images/print.gif" title="Print This Result" alt="Print" border="0">
<Div id="DivContent" >
Hello there
</Div>
```

Or you can try to add the CSS print.

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets

http://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/

Comment: I am afraid this will not help, path and date are added by browser, it should be turn off from print setup dialog

Comment: I have mentioned some jQuery options too,try those